.NET 8 (isolated worker model) PUT/POST methods have null body
I have recently updated from .NET 6 to .NET 8, now using the isolated worker model.
Everything went fine, but after some more testing I've realized that a few POST/PUT methods are now receiving the body as null.
Some mentions: I am using OpenAPI generator and Newtonsoft.Json (investigated around this for a solution as I thought this needs to be replaced with System.Text.Json - but the generator has Newtonsoft.Json).
While debugging, the only place before my method seems to be in the DirectFunctionExecutor.
E.g. for the function below, what I receive is a null body
[Function("doSomething")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method1(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "version/myRoute")][FromBody] string body, HttpRequest req,
        Logger logger)

So far I don't understand what happened in this case.
If you have any input, please leave it here.

Check if the request body is being deserialized correctly by the Newtonsoft.Json serialization.
I have modified your code and able to implement Post method in the .NET8 Isolated Azure functions.
Code Snippet:
[Function("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "version/myRoute")] HttpRequest req, ILogger logger)
{
   string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
   return new OkObjectResult(requestBody+", Welcome to Azure Functions!");
}

Response:

Passing body in the text format.


Console response:
[2024-04-23T09:03:29.518Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 22184) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-04-23T09:03:29.648Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: [POST] http://localhost:7018/api/version/myRoute

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-04-23T09:03:34.768Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-04-23T09:05:13.088Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=6558dae2-da77-484d-8cc3-b66f8837dec2)
[2024-04-23T09:05:13.725Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-04-23T09:05:13.862Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=6558dae2-da77-484d-8cc3-b66f8837dec2, Duration=825ms)


Just something to check it looks like you're using MVC integration for isolated worker. This might mean your FromBody attribute is from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, which wouldn't work and would result in a null object.
You need to use the following in order for the FromBody to work, it's a bit annoying but seems to be how it's set up at the moment.
using FromBodyAttribute = Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.FromBodyAttribute;


Global usings makes it easy to have namespace collisions like that unfortunately.
